# Closing gitlab merge request

Tags: merge, request, gitlab

We are using Gitlab (the gitlab.com free version).  My colleague is creating merge requests and we are merging from one branch (development) into another (master).  When my colleague merges into master the MR is shown as Merged.  I am then running some tests on the merged branch (not done automatically through GL currently) and when happy with the merge I am wanting to close the merge request.  However I do  not have any option to close it - I do not have a close button and if I type /close in the comments it does not do anything.
Neither my colleague or myself are able to close the MRs.  We both have Master status and have tried changing various MR project settings but to no avail.
PLease can anyone help?

Comment: Something is missing

Comment: Sorry, I put tags on before I had finished and it posted before I was ready.  I have now completed the question.  Thanks

Comment: You merge the branch before testing it? What if that test fails? Would you revert the merge? Why not test **before** merging, like everybody else does?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Gitlab, the `merged` status means the relevant commits have been merged and no action is needed.

A `closed` merge request is one that has been put aside or considered irrelevant. It is therefore not merged into the code base.

Therefore, you only `merge` MRs when you're happy with the changes and `close` them if you think the changes are not worthy of being integrated into the code base ever.

A typical workflow would be the following:

- User A works on a new feature in a feature branch and pushes their work to that branch.
- They can open a merge request to merge their feature branch into master.
- User B pulls the feature branch, eventually rebasing it onto master, and runs the tests they want.
- If User B is happy with the changes/new feature, they can merge the MR  into master (or whatever branch you merge into)
- The merge request will be shown as merged

Of course it's better if the tests run automatically in a CI.

Comment: Thank you.  Our workflow is is different to the above.  Currently there is only one developer who works on the development branch (they do not create a feature branch).  WHen they have completed working on a feature/bug they perform a merge request and merge with master.  The code from master is then deployed to the Staging server where it is tested.  If it passes testing the code from the master branch is then deployed to the live server.

Comment: You might be better off deploying the code from the development branch to your staging server and test it. If the tests pass then merge into master and deploy master to the live server (doesn't hurt to test master again before deploying). My 2 cents...

Comment: @Jawad Thanks for your answer. I was starting to bash that "Close Merge Request" button with annoyance and frustration :)

Comment: That is very bad UI. My team is new to Git and we incorrectly assumed that close means we're done or something. It should say something clearly negative such as 'revoke', 'deny', etc.

Comment: It might be a little confusing to people new to git but this is consistent with the terms used on all major git providers such as Github, Bitbucket and of course Gitlab

Comment: You've got to realise there's a two stage process in GitLab: you create or open a merge request and then you either merge it or close it. So you can open then merge (finished approved) or open then close (finished denied).

Answer (score 3):

With GitLab 12.2 (August 2019), you have new options which could help indicate the "closed" status of a merge request.

See "[New push options for merge requests](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/08/22/gitlab-12-2-released/#new-push-options-for-merge-requests)"

> In GitLab 12.2, GitLab has been taught new push options to:
>
> - Set the branch to be removed when it is merged.
> - Change the merge request’s title.
> - Change the merge request’s description.

See [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/64320) and [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#git-push-options)

Comment: My understanding is that "closed" does not mean "merged" for GitLab, it means "aborted" or "deleted" or "dropped" or something. Documentation doesn't explicitly describe what the actions are, it might be just "forget that we requested this merge". I think it would be good if you never used the word "closed" to mean "merged"; it's exactly and confusingly wrong.